# Connection String to an SQL server MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-4

i am making an online shop mvc web , i made a table for categories and filled it with data , and made a table for products and filled it with data, now how to connect to these database to preview them on web (NOTE: i want to press on store on web , then it will take us to categories then after pressing categories we will have the products in these categories.
This is my Store Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCOnlineShop.Models;

namespace MVCOnlineShop.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        OnlineStoreEntities storeDB = new OnlineStoreEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Store/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Categories = storeDB.Categories.ToList();
            return View(Categories);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Store/Browse
        public ActionResult Browse(string Category)
        {
            // Retrieve Category and its Associated Products from database
            var CategoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Products")
                .Single(g => g.Name == Category);

            return View(CategoryModel);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Store/Details
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var Product = storeDB.Products.Find(id);

            return View(Product);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Store/Browse?Category=Games

    }
}
```

Can you please give me the correct form of connection string to an SQL server

Comment: you must be using entity framework right? there you are providing connection & all. I guess you dont have to worry about the connection.

Comment: is there any codes should i use to connect these data in tables?

Comment: no when you add edmx in your project you provide connection string & connect to the DB, & then you can add entities (table) in your project.

Comment: i filled my tables in VS , then made relation ship in sql 1 category to many products, now how to preview them on web? (NOTE: i want to press on store on web , then it will take us to categories then after pressing categories we will have the products in these categories)

Comment: I reckon you should go through this article. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683942/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-for-understanding-E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press f12 on OnlineStoreEntities class then check the connectionString mentioned in OnlineStoreEntities :base("connectionstringName") .
Check the connection string name in webconfig.
In web config you can change the connection string values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

go through this tutorial for DB first approach .

Comment: what to write in web config to connect to my sql server?

Comment: do i have to import my database on sql? because i saw a tutorial about adding in app_data .mdf file , this .mdf is from importing database in sql?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

follow this tutorial  and apply DB first approach.

Comment: and in app_data , where can i find the .mdf file?

Comment: please go through this tutorial and you have to create a .mdf file

Comment: i went through it , but didnt know how to get a .mdf file

Comment: when will you add  Ado.net Data Model that will create a mdf file for you.

Comment: i added in model , w ado.net model , and all done , but still where can i find this mdf file? sorry for too many questions , but i am a beginner in MVC and still learning it , thanks!

Comment: sorry mdf file not required here from edmx file you can get all your database operations.

Comment: thanks , now how to preview on web , i have this store controller , i wrote it in the question

Comment: use the created classes from edmx so you can get that

Comment: can you give me some codes please, you have my store controller what should i do in its index and details? , i am just a beginner in MVC @Pradeep , thanks!!